# Curves With Known Arc Length

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

I would appreciate if you could list as many (planar) curves with known closed-form analytical expressions for the arc length as possible. Please include formulas for both  the curve and the arc length.  The implicit curves  are of particular interest to me.

---

I might as well start the list :

1. Circle $S^1$

   - implicit equation: $\quad\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)^2 = 1, \quad$ parametrization: $\ \begin{cases} x = r\cos t, \\ y = r\sin t, \end{cases} \  t \in [0, 2\pi)$.
   - arc length $ s(t) =  r\cdot t, \ t \in [0, 2\pi)$, and $s(x,y) = r \cdot \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), \ 0\le x,y\leq r $.
2. Parabola with focal length $f$, perpendicular distance to the axis of symmetry  $p$.

   - implicit equation: $\left( x - h\right)^2 = 4 p \, (y-k)$.
   - arc length from the vertex of parabola $s = \frac{hq}{f} + f \ln \left( \frac{h+q}{f}\right)$, $h = p/2$, $q = \sqrt{f^2 + h^2}$.
3. $ y =  x^2 - \frac{1}{8}\ln x $.

   - arc length  from the point $(1,1)$: $\ s(x) =  x^2 + \frac{1}{8}\ln x - 1$.

---

**PS:** Please do not hesitate to post curves in higher dimensions.

Comment: You can calculate the arclength of the exponential function, it takes a few changes of variable, but it's doable.

Comment: I am very curious where your study is leading to. Are there any patterns that you are trying to find out? That would be interesting to know.

Comment: @cgo I am simply trying to collect a representative set of curves of different types in order to use them as test cases for an algorithm I am developing

Comment: Why do people think that this question is too broad? I explicitly ask to list very specific type of curves, whichever anyone could come up with. Possible answers are not going to be too long, and even though there are many curves following the imposed condition, my ultimate goal is to make _one unique_ list which includes all these curves. My goal is not necessarily collect all possible curves of the form, but rather to obtain a comprehensive and broad, yet finite (limited) collection for a specific use.

Answer (score 3):

Catenary,
$f=\cosh(x)$,
since
$f'(x)
=\sinh(x)
$
so
$\sqrt{f'^2(x)+1}
=\sqrt{\sinh^2(x)+1}
=\cosh(x)
=f(x)
$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Calculate the arc length of the graph of the function $y = x^{3/2}$ between the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.
2. Calculate the arc length of the graph of the function $y = (1/4) x^2-(1/2) \ln x$, between the points $(1,1/4)$ and $\bigl(e,(e^2-2)/4\bigr)$.
3. Calculate the arc length of the cycloid given by the parametric equations
   \[
   x(t) = t- \sin(t), \quad y(t) = 1-\cos(t) \quad \text{where} \quad 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi.
   \]
4. Calculate the arc length of the astroid curve given by the parametric equations
   \[
   x(t) = (\cos t)^3, \quad y(t) = (\sin t)^3 \quad \text{where} \quad 0 \leq  t \leq 2 \pi.
   \]
5. Calculate the arc length of the spiral given by the parametric equations
   \[
   x(t) = (\exp t)(\cos t), \quad y(t) = (\exp t)(\sin t) \quad \text{where} \quad -\pi \leq t \leq \pi.
   \]

Comment: These are very nice examples, but I was more interested in curves which can be given as a level-set of some function, i.e. the implicit curves.

Answer (score 2):

The [tractrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html) has parametric equations:
$$
x(t)=a(t-\tanh (t)) \qquad y(t)=a \mbox{ sech }( t)
$$
and the arc length is: $s(t)=a \ln (\cosh (t))$.

A curve with  implicit equation and simple arc lenght is the [**nephroid**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid):
$$
108a^4x^2=(x^2+y^2-4a^2)^3
$$
that has  lenght: $L=24a$

And another one is the [**deltoid**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_curve).

Comment: Is there a way to describe tractrix implicitly?

Comment: Ies. You can use equation (1) in my reference,. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix for another form.

Comment: Vlad: I have added some other curves that has implicit equations.

Comment: @Vlad Tractrix has constant tangent length to x-axis. Try googling Cycloid, Catenary, Cardoid, Epicycloid, curves of constant width, Involute Lemniscate of Bernoulli etc.

Comment: @Narasimham Cool, thank you!

Comment: http://2dcurves.com/    you have them all at one place.